# Get input values from a grid with several Entry widgets on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, input

I'm trying to create a sudoku solver. I have my grid with the entries at this point but I don't know how to get the values that the user has put in them.

I have no clue yet as to how I'm going to make the Sudoku solver but I think I'll first have to find a way to store the input in some variable(s) so I can work with them later on.

So my question is, how do I get the values that have been filled into the entries?

This is my code thus far:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Sudoku Solver')
root.geometry('500x400')

mylabel = Label(root, text='Fill in the numbers and click solve').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)

# Create the grid
def beg():
    global e
    cells = {}
    for row in range(1, 10):
        for column in range(1, 10):
            if ((row in (1,2,3,7,8,9) and column in (4,5,6)) or (row in (4,5,6) and column in (1,2,3,7,8,9))):
                kleur='black'
            else:
                kleur='white'
            cell = Frame(root, bg='white', highlightbackground=kleur,
                         highlightcolor=kleur, highlightthickness=2,
                         width=50, height=50,  padx=3,  pady=3, background='black')
            cell.grid(row=row, column=column)
            cells[(row, column)] = cell
            e = Entry(cells[row, column], width=4, bg='white', highlightthickness=0, fg='black', relief=SUNKEN)
            e.pack()



# Tell the button what to do
def solve():
    global e
    test = e.get()
    print(test)

# Create the buttons and give them a command
clearer = Button(root, text='Clear', command=beg)
solver = Button(root, text='Solve', command=solve)

# Locate the buttons
clearer.grid(row=11, column=3, pady=30)
solver.grid(row=11, column=7, pady=30)

# Run it for the first time
beg()

root.mainloop()
```

I also tried changing e to e[row, column] but that gave me a syntax error.

Comment: you have to keep all `Entries` on list. You can't keep many elements in variable using `e = ...`. You need `e = []` and use `e.append()`. And later you get get values using loops `for item in e: print(e.get())`. If you will keep in 2-dimensional list then you could use `e[row][col].get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard rule: if you have many elements then keep them on list or dictionary.

Do the same as with `cells`

Create dictionary

```
entries = {}
```

add to dictionary

```
entries[(row, column)] = e
```

and get from dictionary

```
def solve():
    for row in range(1, 10):
        for column in range(1, 10):
            print(row, column, entries[(row, column)].get() )
```

---

```
# from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

# Create the grid
def beg():

    # remove old widgets before creating new ones
    for key, val in cells.items():
        print(key, val)
        val.destroy()


    for row in range(1, 10):
        for column in range(1, 10):
            if ((row in (1,2,3,7,8,9) and column in (4,5,6)) or (row in (4,5,6) and column in (1,2,3,7,8,9))):
                kleur='black'
            else:
                kleur='white'

            cell = tk.Frame(root, bg='white', highlightbackground=kleur,
                         highlightcolor=kleur, highlightthickness=2,
                         width=50, height=50,  padx=3,  pady=3, background='black')
            cell.grid(row=row, column=column)
            cells[(row, column)] = cell

            e = tk.Entry(cell, width=4, bg='white', highlightthickness=0, fg='black', relief='sunken')
            e.pack()

            entries[(row, column)] = e

# Tell the button what to do
def solve():
    for row in range(1, 10):
        for column in range(1, 10):
            print(row, column, entries[(row, column)].get() )

# --- main ---

entries = {}
cells = {}

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Sudoku Solver')
root.geometry('500x400')

mylabel = tk.Label(root, text='Fill in the numbers and click solve')
mylabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)

# Create the buttons and give them a command
clearer = tk.Button(root, text='Clear', command=beg)
solver = tk.Button(root, text='Solve', command=solve)

# Locate the buttons
clearer.grid(row=11, column=2, pady=30, columnspan=3) # I added `columnspan=3`
solver.grid(row=11, column=6, pady=30, columnspan=3) #  I added `columnspan=3`

# Run it for the first time
beg()

root.mainloop()
```